# Java script function to Add one hour to the "DD/name of the month/YYYY HH:MM:SS" format

Tags: javascript

I have a date format like this 15/name of the month/2016 Hr:MM:SS this is coming to me as a string. I want to add one hour to the input string and display it as Local time.

I am trying to substring this but the format is not consistent as the name of the month has many characters in "November" and with "July".

Can any one please suggest how to to with this.. I am looking at regular expressions but i am not sure if reg helps...

Comment: Convert it to a `Date` first and then modify that?

Comment: Indeed. Convert to date, get the ms since epoch, add 3600000 ms (one hour) convert back to date. This way you don't have to deal with stuff like leap years and month boundries if you add an hour to a date past 11PM.

Comment: use `var array = dateStr.split(/[\/\s:]/)` and crate Date object from array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function UTCTime() {
        var time = "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM\PM";
        var months = ["Jan", 'Feb', "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        var array = dtc_time.split(/[\/\s:]/);
        var d = new Date(array[2], array[0] - 1, array[1], array[3], array[4], array[5], 0);
        d.setHours(array[3] - 1);            
        var time = formatAMPM(d);
        var local = d.getDate() + "/" + months[d.getMonth()] + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + time;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = local.fontcolor("white");
    }
    function formatAMPM(date) {
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();
        var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + ampm;
        return strTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will allow you to add one hour and convert to local time.

```
var dateString = "15/January/2016 23:59:59";
// Replace slashes
var dateStringReplaced = dateString.replace('/', ' ');
// Parse date
var date = new Date(Date.parse(dateStringReplaced));
// Add an hour
date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1);
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

https://jsbin.com/tecosovaki/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Can you also please suggest how to display it back to the same format as have to display date in "DD/name of Month//YYYY HH:MM:SS  AM\PM" format

Comment: This example shows you how to convert it back.
https://jsbin.com/sujuzexuli/edit?js,console
Although if this was the original intention of your question, I would kindly suggest modyfying your question to reflect this.

Comment: My previous example is 24hr time. To get AM\PM, you can change the time format to "en-AU" in my example. With the string.replace() removed, you will get this: "‎16‎ ‎January‎ ‎2016‎ ‎12‎:‎59‎:‎59‎ ‎AM". You can then find a way to insert the slashes.

Comment: The above method is working fine with chrome but it is displaying as NaN/undefined/NaN 12:NaN:NaN AM format in IE.. Is there anything i am missing... Please help

Comment: Which version of IE, I ran both jsbin samples in IE11 before publishing the answer, and it ran without issue. Which method are you trying, as there is my answer and the comments I provided? Are you running the exact same code as my example, or are there changes you have included.